# MVC: When returning from the controller on Ajax call, the result is undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I'm making an Ajax call to the controller when clicking on a Kendo button and return the model:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("btnSubmit")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })
                    .Icon("rotate")
                    .Content("View Details"))

<script>
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({

            url: "/MyController/MyMethod/",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("RedirectToView", "MyController", new { myModel = "data" })".replace("data", result);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

The controller's method returns the model:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult MyMethod()
{
    var reportDate = Session["FileDate"] == null ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(Session["FileDate"].ToString());
    var myModel = new MyModel();
    myModel.ColOfData = myModel.GetColOfData(reportDate);
    return Json(myModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I debug my `Ajax` function, result is undefined. The result should be assigned to MyModel, since I'm returning the model back to an `Ajax` function. I need to pass that result to another method in the controller that would return my `Partial View` containing the Grid:

```
public ActionResult RedirectToView(MyModel myModel)
{
    return PartialView("_MyPartialView", myModel);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why in the world are you making an ajax call and then using `location.href` to redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page, and all you are doing is degrading performance. Just make a normal submit and redirect in the POST method)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't related to kendo.

From your controller you have to return a json object like this

```
return Json(new {result=myModel});
```

And in your ajax result you will have your entire model.

After that from the code you provided I am afraid you can't pass your entire model in the url of your GET.

You could probably pass the model Id like that

```
 window.location.href = "@Url.Action("RedirectToView", "MyController", new { id= "modelId" })".replace("modelId", result.Id);
```

And make your action something like that

```
public ActionResult RedirectToView(string id){
    // Get the model data you want .....
    return PartialView("_MyPartialView", myModel);
}
```